# How to redirect old posts with greek characters from Joomla to Worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

I had an old joomla site and my articles contain greek characters like:

```
www.oldwebsite.gr/patiero/item/53372-η-εορτή-του-αγίου-ευθυμίου-στα-ιεροσόλυμα-βιντεο-φωτο
```

And the new website is in Wordpress to:

```
www.newwebsite.gr/patriarxeio-ierosolymon/η-εορτή-του-αγίου-ευθυμίου-στα-ιεροσόλ/
```

In my .htaccess Ι have:

```
# Redirect to www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#custom 301 redirects
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/patiero/item/[0-9]*-(.*)$ http://www.newwebsite.gr/patriarxeio-ierosolymon/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Joomla articles are probably stored in a table named "jos_content". You could search there for such links and replace them with the new ones by running queries, try something like this for each link

```
UPDATE jos_content
SET columnName = REPLACE (columnName, 'www.oldwebsite.gr/patiero/item/53372-η-εορτή-του-αγίου-ευθυμίου-στα-ιεροσόλυμα-βιντεο-φωτο', 'www.newwebsite.gr/patriarxeio-ierosolymon/η-εορτή-του-αγίου-ευθυμίου-στα-ιεροσόλ/')
WHERE columnName LIKE '%www.oldwebsite.gr/patiero/item/53372-η-εορτή-του-αγίου-ευθυμίου-στα-ιεροσόλυμα-βιντεο-φωτο%'
```

where you should replace `columnName` with introtext and fulltext (these are the columns where the text of the article is)

Comment: Thanks for reply, the joomla no longer exists, has been migrate to wordpress and left the old articles on google and creates trouble redirect...